# Rachel Hat Scene

Tags: dialogue, friends

In Friends Season 3 Episode 25 there's the following scene:

> Rachel: (approaching) Hey!
>
> Chandler: Hey!
>
> Joey: Hey-hey, check out the hat!
>
> (She is wearing this giant straw hat, the brim on it must be at least, least foot wide.)
>
> Chandler: **Wait a minute, I know that hat! I was taken aboard that hat! They did experiments on me! I can’t have children!!**
>
> Monica: Seriously, where did you get the hat?
>
> Rachel: Ross gave it to me.
>
> Ross: Yeah, I think she looks good.
>
> Rachel: Ohh, thank you.
>
> Chandler: **Buy it for ya, or win it for ya?**

1. What is Chandler referring to by that sentence about experiments?
2. What does 'Win it for ya' mean?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. I'm pretty sure that this is in reference to the fact it looks like the stereotypical "flying saucer" type alien spaceship. He pretends that he was taken aboard an alien spaceship that looked similar to the hat she was wearing, and was experimented on by the aliens to the extent that he is now possibly infertile.
2. He clearly holds distaste for the hat, therefore when he is told that it was Ross who gave Rachel the hat, he is incredulous about the fact that Ross in fact spent money to buy it. It was simply a further insult about the hat that no one would actually pay money for it, and the only way that Ross could have come to own it would be to win it in some sort of carnival game.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how the first didn't come to me! The second one is exactly how I expected it.